# Running 2 Web Apps onto a Single Java Spring Back End

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, backend, clojurescript

Is it advisable to run 2 Web-apps (written in ClojureScript) onto a single Java Spring Back End?

Context: I have a main web app linked to the existing Java back end. Now I need to create another web-app, with a certain Admin capability. The back end services needed for this new app, are already written in the existing Java back-end. So I had intentions to modify the existing back-end and plug the second one to this as well.

If anyone has past experience doing this, would be great if you could point out some pitfalls to look out for.

Comment: Did'nt quite get you...the other webapp is the extension of the first one??What are you exactly trying to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by "plugging"? Is the web app calling the back-end via APIs? Or are you hosting the web app code in the project and your one project will host two applications? The best way to do it generally is have separate projects for the two web apps, and then use the common backend code either as a library or a microservice (this decision depends on your requirements, as microservices although better require more maintenance and investment).

Comment: @Akshay the other WebApp is not an extension. It is targeting a different user group. So has to be a new app in itself.

Comment: @Rohan Yes the web app is calling back-end via REST APIs.